# Moving, Encrypting and storing .txt and .pc files to .pgp in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, encryption, automation

I have been learning how to use PowerShell to do some automation that will convert files to a .pgp format. These files end in .txt or .qc. These files are created on one of the servers in the environment, then converted manually, then transferred to another server in the same environment.
I have developed a script that will perform this task, however it will only do one file (I would like for to do all of the files). I the script will not strip the native extension and replace it with only a .pgp extension.

I have included the script below.

##### PowerShell Script

```
$_SourcePath = (\\Server1\Location1\*.txt",\\Server1\Location1\*.qc")
$_DestinationPath = "\\Server1\Location2\"
$_SourcePath2 = "\\Server1\Location2\"
$_DestinationPath2 = "\\Server2\Location1\"

Move-item –path $_SourcePath –destination $_DestinationPath

ConvertTo-PgpEncryptedFile -Path "\\Server1\Location2\*.*" -key "\\server3\location1\Enycrption key.asc"

Move-item –path $_SourcePath2 –destination $_DestinationPath2
```

Again, with this script I can move all the files I need, but it will only encrypt one file and move it to the correct location. I would like for it to encrypt all the files and remove the .txt or .qc extension and replace it with .pgp.
Any Help would be appreciated….

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something along this line:

```
$SourcePath       = '\\Server1\Location1\'
$DestinationPath  = '\\Server1\Location2\'
$DestinationPath2 = '\\Server2\Location1\'

$GCIArgs = @{Path  = "$($SourcePath)*" 
             Include = "*.txt","*.qc"
            }
$SrcFiles = Get-ChildItem @GCIArgs

ForEach ($File in $SrcFiles) {

   Move-item –path "$File.FullName" –destination "$DestinationPath"

   $CTPGPArgs = 
     @{Path = $(Join-Path "$DestinationPath"  "$File.Name") 
       Key  = '\\server3\location1\Enycrption key.asc'
      }

   ConvertTo-PgpEncryptedFile @CTPGPArgs

   $EncName = $($_.Name -split('.'))[0] + '.pgp'
   $MIArgs = @{Path        = "$($CTPGPArgs.Path)" 
               Destination = $(Join-Path "$DestinationPath2" "$EncName")
              }
   Move-item @MIArgs
}
```

I've used single quotes in strings where interpretation is not needed. I've also used splatting to shorten lines and make reading easier.

I eliminated the _ in regular variable names so not to confuse them with items from a pipeline.

Used final Move-Item to also change file extension to .pgp.

Note: I tested as much of this as I could piece-meal but not having servers or the cmdlet ConvertTo-PgpEncryptedFile I couldn't test the entire program.